# How to print a certificate's public key length and modulus separately in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I found a method called `getPublicKey()` under the `java.security.cert.Certificate` class, but this methods returns the length, modulus all in one value as a `PublicKey` object. Is there any way to get this information separately ??

Comment: What is the type of the object it is returning?

Comment: Returns: the public key. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getPublicKey(). But in the program's run, the output includes the lenght, and the modulus while I need each value separately.

Comment: This begs the question of, what exactly are you trying to do?  You say you are not storing it somewhere.  Why do you need it?

Comment: I don't want to parse the function return value. But it seems no available method for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are dealing with an RSA based public key the PublicKey object you receive is a [RSAPublicKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html) instance.

Therefore you can cast it to RSAPublicKey and then use it's methods `getPublicExponent()` and `getModulus()`.

Comment: My program supposed to deal not only with RSA pk. Any solutions for this case?

Comment: As only RSA keys will have a modulus this does not make sense. If you want to support other key types as well you have to test for the real PublicKey instance and then cast it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/cert/package-tree.html) for the documentation for the `java.security.cert.*` package, you should find the type of objects you are instantiating.  If you follow the link to the object you will find all of its available methods.  There may be separate methods that return those values, but you'll have to check.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I reached this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html, and found the getPublicKey() and once I tried it, it didn't give me the value in the format I needed & I don't want to store it in a text file and parse it unless there is no possible solution available at all and there should be.